# How do I stop multipass from launching on startup?

Tags: multipass

I've installed [multipass](https://multipass.run/) using this command:

```
sudo snap install multipass
```

Now, there's an ugly orange icon that displays in the system status area ("systray") of GNOME Shell in the top right corner of the screen.

How can I stop multipass from launching upon system startup? Can I disable the icon, at least?

[image]

Comment: Bug report for the icon being in orange instead of black and white: https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1240

Answer (score 2):

### Disabling multipass icon:

Click on the multipass icon, then select "About", then uncheck "Autostart on login".

[image: Screenshot]

(If you think that this option shouldn't be under the "About" menu, leave a thumbs-up emoji in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1244).)

If you prefer the command-line, you can run:

```
multipass set client.gui.autostart=false
```

This option is remembered even after a reboot.

### Stopping multipass from running the background:

Merely disabling the icon does not stop multipass from running in the background. If you want to stop it from running in the background (until the next reboot), run:

```
sudo snap stop multipass.multipassd
```

To start it again, run:

```
sudo snap start multipass.multipassd
```

If you want to disable multipass entirely, without uninstalling it, run:

```
sudo snap disable multipass
```

To enable it again, run:

```
sudo snap enable multipass
```